# Writing data in a text file on server

Tags: javascript, php, fopen, fwrite, file-put-contents

I am trying to build a simple web page where a user is prompt to click on an image as many times as desired. Eventually, after user is done s/he should click a link saying "I'm done" that should trigger the server to write to disk a sting (let's say: "I clicked x times", which I can manage to get).

I tried:

```
<a onclick="WriteNGo()" href="next_index.html">I am Done</a>
```

and of course:

```
function WriteNGo() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'php/save.php',
        data: {writeMe: textToWrite}
    });
}
```

where `textToWrite` is a global variable that contains the string. I can

```
alert(textToWrite)
```

it and get the required sentence.

and added php/save.php at the correct location:

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['writeMe'];
    $f = "../d/data.txt";
    file_put_contents($f,$data,FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

and did a

```
sudo chmod +777 d
```

on the folder.

I only want to end up with a text file containing my string, (i.e. "I clicked x times"). I am not even sure that the POST command triggers the PHP server.

One more thing: the `index.html` is in the root dir, where I am currently running:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

So that there should have not been any problems.

I should also state that there was *one* time that the string was written, though I can't reproduce this it.

Comment: 'data' should be $data to begin with  ```file_put_contents($f,'data',FILE_APPEND);```

Comment: in your javascript where textToWrite does come from ?  ```data: {writeMe: textToWrite}```

Comment: How secure do you want the functionality to be? Can it do with a client-side counter, or do you want to `POST` every click? How do you plan on differentiating several concurrent users? Are these logged in (user ID), or just random visitors (need a generated cookie from the start)? All this has to be considered to produce a reliable solution.

Comment: @Talal of course you were right. It was $data originally. I had changed it to test the php file (didn't work, the word data was not written to file...) and regarding textToWrite - I editted. Thank you.

Comment: @Zdenek I don't care for security, as this page is to be available only via local intranet or even locally. and don't bother with debugging the counter. The issue is with writing the data, as it is accessed by an operator immediately after.

Comment: to prevent wasting your time i suggest using developer tools in your browser and check if the post was sent and after that include this into your php file to return if the script got the post ```exit(var_dump($_POST));``` and check the result in the developer tools and you can handle it from there

Comment: this would exclude post names and 404's and all of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this might address your problem. Maybe, try something like this to see, where your data might be written:

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['writeMe'];
    $path = "../d";

    $dir = $path . "/";

    if (!is_dir($dir)) {mkdir($dir, 0755, true);} 

    // A faster alternative to file_put_content
    $f = $dir . "/data.txt";
    $fp = fopen($f, "x+");
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: It worked! (I admit, I also found a bug at the AJAX function, but this did the trick! :-)